# MongoDB 7.02 starts without replicaset while has Readiness Probe in Openshift 3.11

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, openshift, health-check

I'm trying to add Liveness and Readiness Probe to my MongoDB in Openshift. Without these parameters Mongo can be deployed perfectly every single time. I had to create single node replica set as my backup method requires it, so I need to run Mongo with replicaset. Idk if it's important but I'm using entrypoint.sh instead of CMD in Dockerfile

I'm creating my replicaset like this

```
"rs.initiate(
 {
 _id: 'rs0',
 members: [
 { _id: 0, host: '(openshift-service-name):27017'},
 ]
 });"
```

Then I'm about to add Liveness and Readiness Probe in helm chart

```
           livenessProbe:
             exec:
               command: [ "mongosh", "--host",  "localhost", "--port", "27017", "-u", "admin", "-p", "'admin'", "--authenticationDatabase", "'admin'", "--eval", "'db.getSiblingDB(\"admin\").runCommand({ replSetGetStatus: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2'" ]
             initialDelaySeconds: 70         
             periodSeconds: 60
             failureThreshold: 3
             timeoutSeconds: 20 
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command: [ "mongosh", "--host",  "localhost", "--port", "27017", "-u", "admin", "-p", "'admin'", "--authenticationDatabase", "'admin'", "--eval", "'db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2'" ]
            initialDelaySeconds: 70
            periodSeconds: 60
            failureThreshold: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 20
```

It's interesting as Liveness check with the configuration given above also "corrupts" database, but at the first run it always run normally. However if I kill the pod it's going to be gone.

On the other hand it's impossible to run Readiness Probe as container is permanently in not ready state, does not matter what command I'm going to provide here. For example echo is impossible as well. I've tried to remove initial delay, set is as 10 seconds, have wider timeout frame etc.

I believe there are most important logs:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-18T06:15:34.306+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20711,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Failed to reap transaction table","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-18T06:15:34.306+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":7012500, "ctx":"QueryAnalysisConfigurationsRefresher","msg":"Failed to refresh query analysis configurations, will try again at the next interval","attr":{"error":"PrimarySteppedDown: No primary exists currently"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-18T06:15:34.307+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"connect (sync) TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":30,"data":"01 00 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Protocol not available","message":"Protocol not available","category":"asio.system","value":92}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-18T06:15:34.466+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"ReadConcernMajorityNotAvailableYet: Read concern majority reads are currently not possible.","nextWakeupMillis":400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-18T06:15:36.800+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21394,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"This node is not a member of the config"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-18T06:15:36.800+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21358,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"Replica set state transition","attr":{"newState":"REMOVED","oldState":"STARTUP"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-18T06:16:14.306+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":7012500, "ctx":"QueryAnalysisConfigurationsRefresher","msg":"Failed to refresh query analysis configurations, will try again at the next interval","attr":{"error":"PrimarySteppedDown: No primary exists currently"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait a bit till replica set in initiated. Use a script like this:

```
rs.initiate(
   {
      _id: 'rs0',
      members: [
         { _id: 0, host: '(openshift-service-name):27017' },
      ]
   }
);
while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000);
```

Note, when you connect, then you should also use `readPreference=primaryPreferred`. However, for a single node replica set it is not relevant, of course.

Comment: The initiate is going to be done only once per database server by entrypoint script during an initialization. I do not catch why adding sleep during init is going to resolve. The issue occurs while database is about to reboot. At this point mongod command only is going to be performed