# Mongodb statefulset Kubernetes unable to mounting keyfile with specifique owner

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, mounted-volumes, kubernetes-security

I am currently setting up a MongoDB cluster using a Kubernetes StatefulSet. I have a functional configuration, but it currently runs with the MongoDB daemon starting as root. My goal is to start the StatefulSet with the following security context:
runAsUser: 999
runAsGroup: 999

This corresponds to the 'mongodb' user in the official MongoDB image. For the replica set configuration, I want to use an authentication key.

In my current configuration, which runs as root, my authentication key is mounted into a file using a ConfigMap. When I change my security context, the key becomes unreadable by the MongoDB process because it needs to have permissions set to 400, and the file's owner and group must be 999 (mongodb).

I've tried using FsGroup, but it only changes the group ownership of the file; the owner remains root, and it doesn't work. With an init container, modifying the file permissions also doesn't work, and I receive a message stating that the filesystem is read-only.

Perhaps there is a solution or another way to mount a file with a specific owner inside a pod. Alternatively, I might be using the wrong methodology, which is possible since I'm relatively new to Kubernetes.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  labels:
    name: mongod
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
    protocol: TCP
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongod
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongod
spec:
  serviceName: mongodb-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongod
        replicaset: test
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 999
        runAsGroup: 999
        fsGroup: 999
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 15
      volumes:
        - name: mongodbkey
          configMap:
            name: mongodb-key
            defaultMode: 0400
        - name: mongodb-init
          configMap:
            name: mongodb-init
            defaultMode: 0777
      containers:
        - name: mongod
          image: mongo:7.0.2
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
              /data/mongodbinit/mongo-user.sh &
              mongod --replSet=test --bind_ip_all --auth --dbpath=/data/db --keyFile=/etc/mongodbkey/mongodb.key--setParameter=authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1;
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: mongo-creds          
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                - /bin/bash
                - -c
                - |
                  if [ -f /data/db/admin-user.lock ]; then
                  if [ "$HOSTNAME" != "mongod-0" ]; then
                  mongosh mongod-0.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval 'rs.remove("'$HOSTNAME'.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local:27017")';
                  rm -f /data/db/admin-user.lock; fi; fi;
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - bash
                - -c
                - |
                  if [[ "$(mongosh localhost:27017 -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval 'db.adminCommand({ping:1}).ok' --quiet)" == "1" ]]; then
                  exit 0;
                  else exit 1;
                  fi
            initialDelaySeconds: 90
            periodSeconds: 60
            failureThreshold: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - bash
                - -c
                - |
                  if [[ "$(mongosh localhost:27017 --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval 'db.adminCommand({ping:1}).ok' --quiet)" == "1" ]]; then
                  exit 0;
                  else exit 1;
                  fi
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            periodSeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 0.2
              memory: 200Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongodb-persistent-storage-claim
              mountPath: /data/db
            - name: mongodbkey
              mountPath: /etc/mongodbkey/mongodb.key
              subPath: mongodb.key
            - name: mongodb-init
              mountPath: /data/mongodbinit
            
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongodb-persistent-storage-claim
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "standard"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-key
data:
  mongodb.key: |
    aP+dcZjtBO3Qjvwm2oaxjhYsGrezOi6oV49+dbpON8mTiyW0Zr359EUCYcLn/QcU
    3jPmPDnil1mdoIevcz1z/GF17gbmFVBFR9H24DMAeDzxzHhVusVp0NN6dn0mhCcO
    vQUaG9uTxKPAthkwG1JJJQwmzwhc5cXIq51hY5Ea6IoAWmxebvqohRjWf8KjXXE6
    ji0XguppRKEHk4LEZMoeztjAaSKFn/DF9IXuraHtR1RqViDbExQYc9Db/obUS1jN
    80dR7GpvE5IExju3uSSOv1LkjVgWHz/02sdk8qc9p/R6Zua6D/HuCI6OFYJ2btYq
    bIJ4rpphmI06d64XFzWexQeLpOSGBJQt+630U7GzcQHM9ARUYybrSoQ39i3w1Wci
    lMZq96AGh24WVWenIgKons0BOW4LH2RljUHl7XeSC3HC+3DtqHIuUa5I9JiAp0Ch
    8xnAcJuWr0ZQJDHr8iOJCWteOr+CMKy/UTgI96xYsq36YV+Ch/swNBVfHVsZQoIj
    jqGNh3EhZ266wZBUXrL7xfimxCvQlEGcklbew3WyIRBrWsIXm3Wf8KTz4wmYp4Cs
    petISeEAr2Lh2Bv2SBDXPF4RCFEfgDJvszPUHAkMTp2khO22s08ohYfq8ebMx6hC
    U3AnnbGtFqQ3PUdtWstPKoRLWp3cM6hc6rRECIpkJhzkPT9J2cmtwxLwvlKoSDZw
    UzZFptrD9I19xNP5QGacmIJCwFIm0Wwnv1bZUKz5+JopqyAPoTeq1k9J3bq2fRIX
    2ArTDUPqluqzlNI1PBM6+5A58arR+eSNQMfmOKfQVA6LV5kQruJrolFQIwqsnBwy
    Hf/OlHSjYR7gCRpd6Mh+O3hgd1baq+DnQgSGbsc+5qJks9sC4c0i1JIggM09+90g
    EMaS4C5m7YTgnHGUPDMS2iSr+lsxurrhR8h/3vU4JBMuGQysQpTpv1VpYxIFUhyq
    fCTVBz7aLengL4DxgEqwfLoDtIrMeMZuEyblNnH9G3oEBxnvJpY83vfHweVrneS7
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-init
data:
  mongo-user.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    if [ ! -f /data/db/admin-user.lock ]; then
    sleep 45;
    if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "mongod-0" ]; then
      mongosh admin --eval 'rs.initiate({_id: "test", members: [{ _id: 0, host: "mongod-0.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local" }]})';
    else
      sleep 40;
      mongosh mongod-0.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local -u ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME} -p ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD} --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval 'rs.add( { host: "'${HOSTNAME}'.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local" } )'; fi;
    touch /data/db/admin-user.lock;
    fi;
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: dXNlcjE=
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: dXNlcjE=

kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: mongo-creds
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `rs.remove()`? As I understand you create a single-node replica set. You cannot remove a member from replica set when you have only one member.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but would be relevant anyway:

You should not do anything manually in `dbPath` (i.e. `/data/db/`) folder. What is the reason for checking/deleting/creating `/data/db/admin-user.lock`? If you like to check whether the replica set has been initiated already, you can use

```
ret=$( mongosh --eval 'try { rs.status() } catch (e) { print(e.codeName) }' )
[[ "$ret" == "NotYetInitialized" ]] && mongosh admin --eval 'rs.initiate(...)'
```

And as already mentioned in [MongoDB 7.02 starts without replicaset while has Readiness Probe in Openshift 3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77837356/mongodb-7-02-starts-without-replicaset-while-has-readiness-probe-in-openshift-3/77837608) you should add

```
while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000)
```

after `rs.initiate()`, otherwise the `mongosh` may terminate before replica set has been fully initiated.